# How to make intermediate object file not a library using qmake?

Tags: qt5, static-linking, qmake

Filesystem layout:

```
MyProject
|_ myproject.pro
|_ FuncA
   |_ core.cpp
   |_ core.h
   |_ core.pro
|_ app
   |_ main.cpp
   |_ app.pro
```

I want just to compile "core.cpp" in FuncA to make a object file not a library. That is "gcc -c core.cpp". And in app I want to make main program linking core.o created previously.

In this case how do I make core.pro? Which TEMPLATE should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with "static library config" so that it will not make ".so" libs and then link that static library with main program.

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use generic `app` template for `core.pro`. It will create intermediate `core.o` anyway, which you can link later in `app.pro` like so:

```
LIBS += $$PWD/../FuncA/core.o
```